# Android sdk issues with virtual device

Tags: android, sdk

I am having a problem that when i go to the sdk manager and when i want to create a new avd,there is a problem that:

> > when i set the name after then, target texboxt is unchecked and i am not able to write the target there and CPU/ABI is also unselected,i am not able to do anything with them.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are not installed android sdk propery. Update the android sdk manager and check first whether android sdk tools are installed properly.

Comment: so do u want to say that i have to update and install all the packages?because i have tried what u suggested...@coder decoder encoder

Comment: I want to add one thing that when i download the packages it shows me the message that file is not found.help me out.

Comment: The error massage:
"file not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\tools_r19-windows.zip (Access is denied)"

Comment: i think your operating system does not android sdk to install automatically. try it manually